# Concatenate uri with # in java using UriComponentsBuilder

Tags: java, url, path

Following is my code base:

```
String url = "http://sample.domain.com"; // it may ends with '#param=value
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url);

Map<String, String> uriVariables = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder();

// fill uriVariables and params
```

At the end value of `params` is `param1={param1}&param2={param2}`.

`uriVariables` is used to substitute `{param1}` and `{param2}` in `params`.

My question is, How can I use `builder` to generate url like?

`url#params` or `url#param=value&params`

e.g.

- http://sample.domain.com#param1=value1&param2=value2
- http://sample.domain.com#param=value&param1=value1&param2=value2

I tried `builder.pathSegment(String...)` but it results to

http://sample.domain.com/%23/param1=value1&param2=value2

Answer (score 0):

Try using [UriComponentsBuilder.fragment()](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#fragment(java.lang.String))

e.g. `builder.fragment("param=value")`

Comment: this removes my existing fragment. For e.g. param=value in my above example.